# Dart: How to reduce a list of classes

Tags: dart

I want to reduce a list of classes for example:

```
class Product {
  final String name;
  final double price;

  Product({this.name, this.price});
}

List<Product> products = [
  Product(name: 'prod1', price: 100.0),
  Product(name: 'prod2', price: 300.0),
];

void main() {
  var sum = products.reduce((curr, next) => curr.price + next.price);
  print(sum);
}
```

but it throws an error

Error: A value of type 'double' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Product'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The syntax for the reduce method are specified as:

```
reduce(E combine(E value, E element)) → E
```

So the method should return the same type as the two input. In you case the curr and next values are of the type Product but your are returning a double value.

What you properly want to use are instead the fold method:

```
fold<T>(T initialValue, T combine(T previousValue, E element)) → T
```

So you code would be:

```
class Product {
  final String name;
  final double price;

  Product({this.name, this.price});
}

List<Product> products = [
  Product(name: 'prod1', price: 100.0),
  Product(name: 'prod2', price: 300.0),
];

void main() {
  var sum = products.fold(0, (sum, next) => sum + next.price);
  print(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it using

```
var sum = products.map((product) => product.price).reduce((v, e) => v + e);
print ("$sum"); // prints 400.0
```

Comment: Yeah, this was my first approach but want it to do it using reduce. Thanks!

Comment: this is more cleaner... folds gives me errors